# Prove : $ P(B|A) + P(B|A') =1$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I came across this question in my test and could not solve it. Do I have to prove it using $P(B|A) + P(B'|A) = 1?$

Note: $B' = B^c$

Comment: You can't prove $P(B|A)+P(B|A^c)=1$ because it's false in general, but $P(B|A)+P(B^c|A)=1$ is always true.

Comment: @Fakemistake he is trying to prove $P(B|A) + P(B^c|A) = 1$ ..

Comment: @infinity And what is that in the header?

Comment: did you mean $P(B/A) + P(B/A') = P(B)$?

Comment: @Fakemistake i think he just had a typo, in the body of the question he corrected it

Comment: @infinity No! He asked how to prove the formula in the header using the formula in the body.

Comment: @Fakemistake ops. sorry, then i will correct my answer.

Comment: ... and that is why [a question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969): After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: I am trying to prove P(B/A) + P(B/A') =1 and not  P(B/A) + P(B'/A) =1.

Comment: @Fakemistake thanks for the correction, i updated my answer

Comment: @Matix this claim is false, see my answer.

Comment: I went through it.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misinterpreted your question, here is a proof for the true statement $P(B|A) + P(B'|A) =1$ :
$P(B|A) = \dfrac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}$, 
$P(B'|A) = \dfrac{P(B'\cap A)}{P(A)}$

Now sum it up to get

$P(B|A) +P(B'|A) = \dfrac{P(B\cap A)}{P(A)}+ \dfrac{P(B'\cap A)}{P(A)} = \dfrac{P(B\cap A)+P(B'\cap A)}{P(A)}$

Now, what is $P(B\cap A)+P(B'\cap A) $ ?

---

Now, $P(A|B) + P(A|B') =1$ is false, for example : 
$\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$ with uniform probability.

Take $A=\{1\} B=\{1,2\}$ then $P(A|B)=1/2$ and $P(A|B')=0$ and the sum is not $1$.

Comment: Note that the question (apparently) asks to prove $P(B|A)+P(B|A^c)=1$.

Comment: @MartinR thanks, fixed my answer.